# React native and arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, performance, function, react-native, arrow-functions

In React for web, for performance we should not use arrow functions in case `onPress`, `onClick`, etc.

Is this rule also valid for React Native?

Comment: The JS part of RN is still just JS and subject to the same conditions. Whether or not their use leads to poor performance is highly context-dependent, e.g., it may never matter that you have some arrow functions as handlers.

Answer (score 0):

"Learn Once, Write Anywhere". JavaScript, if not already, is on the verge of becoming the winner of all races. React-Native is another beautiful JavaScript library (Some prefer 'framework'). Since it's JavaScript, the rules and conditions are same for RN as they are for any other JS library.

Performance is not the main point of comparison here. Actually there should be no comparison anyway. It's the effectiveness and the readability of the code. Fat arrow function is one of the most relevant change JS paradigm. They allow calling anonymous functions and deals with ever existing scope dilemma by changing the way `this` binds to the function. For example `onPress = {this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}` simply becomes `onPress = {() => this.onButtonPress}`. If you still find it tedious to declare a function, you can do something like this

`onPress = {() => {
this.props.navigation.navigate('HomePage')
}}`

to save time and code quicker although this **should not be** your usual practice, rather go with the traditional way.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're actually answering the question. Instead of a bunch of unrelated text, it might be better to directly address the question, by providing an example of "the traditional way" (whatever you believe that to be) compared with "the new way", and then address the underlying issue: which should be done, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow functions as class properties is ideal because it doesn't create its own scope.

If you have an arrow function inside a life cycle method (e.g. render), it does decrease the efficiency of your code because you are creating a new function every time that method is called, but that's ok because the decrease in performance will be negligible.

Comment: Whether or not it becomes a performance issue depends on things like how often the component is re-rendered, how many of the components there are on the page, etc., same as in React.

Answer (score 0):

Both are there for their own reasons. Performance isn't much issue.
Normally `React-Native` apps use arrow functions all the time. 
It is depends on the requirement. For example if you have a button and on its onPress prop It would be better to pass an arrow function as it won't need binding. You should use normal functions (not arrow functions) in case you need the reference to `this` from which it is defined. 
Arrow functions are also very flexible and you should use those advantages.
So, I would suggest using of arrow functions and normal functions if you need `this`. I personally use normal functions only if i need `this`.